# Can't convert a string to JSON using python 3?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I have a response object of byte type into convert to JSON and get data from it.
 `response = b'{"message": "test msg 3"}'`

My code  :

```
        try:
            response = response.decode('utf-8')
            LOGGER.info(response)
            data = json.load(response)
            message = data["message"]
        except AttributeError as err:
            message = "Message not delivered..."
            LOGGER.warning(err)
```

When `response.decode('utf-8')` executes it become  `{"message": "test msg 3"}`

But Each time i am getting a error while executing `json.load(response)`:

```
'str' object has no attribute 'read'
```

Can anyone point me why this happening ?

**Solution :**

Use `json.loads()` instead of `json.load()` . Because `json.load()` loads a file and `json.loads()` loads a String.

Comment: [`json.load`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.load) tries to load from a file (or other readable object). [`json.loads`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.loads) accepts a string.

Comment: Thanks @khelwood